# sonar runner authorization error

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I'm trying to send a job to sonarqube from jenkins. However I'm getting an error saying te following when I run the job

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: Not authorized. Please check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password.
```

The system I'm using is as follows. I have `jenkins 2.7.1`, `SonarQube 5.6` and `SonarQube Runner 2.4` is installed on my server as well.

To log in to jenkins and sonarqube I'm using a ldap that only holds ldap users, no local users exists.

In my jenkins settings I set up SonarQube as follows
[image]

the token was created in a admin account in SonarQube
[image]

When I created the job I made a new build step for a sonarqube scanner. Inside my project I created a sonar-project.properties file that holds the following information

```
sonar.projectKey=org.sonarqube:php-ut-sq-scanner
sonar.projectName=vanbenthem :: PHPUnit :: SonarQube Scanner
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.sources=src
sonar.tests=tests

sonar.language=php

sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

# Reusing PHPUnit reports
sonar.php.coverage.reportPath=reports/phpunit.coverage.xml
sonar.php.tests.reportPath=reports/phpunit.xml
```

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? To my understanding I shouldn't be giving a login and password since SonarQube 5.4
Hope someone will be able to help me out

**per nicloas' request**

Here are the console output from jenkins and my sonar settings regarding my ldap.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The sonar-runner command executed should be printed in the console output, please add it to your question. Also paste the LDAP-related part of you `sonar.properties` (server side) as it might interfere with how permissions are managed in SonarQube.

Comment: @Nicolas I updated my question with screenshots from both

Comment: Have you specified the token value as the `sonar.login` property?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I faced the same issue with Bitbucket pipelines and Sonarqube. It turned out that the Sonarqube authentication token I was using was incorrect. It is configured as `SONAR_TOKEN` in Bitbucket's repository variables and correcting it solved the issue.

Please make sure to double check the `Server authentication token` you are entering here.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the token provided by Sonarqube and stored in Jenkins is correct

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).